# IE does not recognising .less file

Tags: css, less

I create a less file which is working fine in chrome and firefox, but not even recognising in IE 9. Can anyone please suggest what needed to run it in IE 9.0. below is the css sample..

```
@import "../core/variables.less"; @import "Mixins.less";

.classname {

    @fontweight:bold;
    @width:99.9%;
    @height:67px;
    @color:#D3E2F2;
    @icon-width:10px;
    @icon-height:10px;

    .div-carddropdownbox{
             width:90%;
        }
    .span(@fontweight)
    {
        font-weight:@fontweight;
    }
     .span-underline(){
            .span(bold);
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
     .span-bold{
           .span(bold);
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

    .div(@width,@height)
    {
        float:left;
        width:@width;
        height:@height;  
        padding-top: 10px;  
        padding-bottom: 10px;  
    }
    .div-tracethistransaction
    {
        .div(100%,100%);
        border:1px solid black; 
    }
    .div-servicerequestcharge{
           .div(99.9%,67px);    
            background-color:@color;
            border:1px solid black;
    }
    .div-account
    {
            .div(99.9%,35px);    
            background-color:@color;

    }
    .div-white-blank
    {
         .div(99.9%,2px);
    }
    .div-button
    {
        padding-top:110px;
    }
    .div-carddelivered
    {
        .div(100%,45px); 

    }

    .icon(@icon-width,@icon-height)
    {
            width:@icon-width;
            height:@icon-height;
    }
    .div-icon
    {
        .icon(20px,20px);
        padding-left: 580px;
    }

    .round-button-cancel {
        .rounded-button (7px, #ECECEC, #A9A9A9,none, bold, #52504C,
90px, 35px);
    }

    .round-button-submit {
        .rounded-button (7px, #FAF5E9, #EFAE2C,none, bold, #8B4513,
Auto, 35px);
    }

}
```

Comment: You did include less.js, right?

Comment: I am new for less and did not find less.js file in my solution.

Comment: can you please tell me what does this less.js file do? where to download this file?

Comment: If you have the script but it still doesn't work, I can't help further. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [LESS site](http://lesscss.org/), it says that it doesn't support IE. None of its versions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're including the less.js script.  It's needed to parse less files.
http://lesscss.org/

If this is a .NET project, and you don't want to use less.js (which can add overhead on the client-side for larger .less files), you could add the DotLess library to your project.
http://www.dotlesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue. I simply compile it into a `.css` file and reference that for live testing, including IE.